# Enumerate k part of n (and keep the list)

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, partitioning

I failed to "keep" the combinaison of k after doing a partition of n. I'm starting to understand the problem and how it is resolve, I just don't know how to stack values when I go back up the tree.

It's a bit of a coding problem as it is a recursion one.

I have :

```
def p(n,k):
    lst = []
    if n < k:
        return 0
    elif k == 1:
       #somehow append subset (k',k',k') to lst
    elif k == n:
       #somehow append subset (k',k',k') to lst
    else:
        p(n-1, k-1)
        p(n-k, k)
        # return p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k, k) -- gives the sum, that's where i'm now
    return lst

print p(7,3)

#I want [(5,1,1), (4,2,1), (3,3,1), (3,2,2)]
```

I get the part k == 1, but I failed to stack the + 1 ... (k-1 time) to get (5,1,1). Same goes for the k == n base case. Bonus question if i may, how to you get a k of (3,2,2)?

Thank you

Comment: What does your code output now (for the p(7,3))?  It might help if you explained a little more clearly what you were looking for.  I originally thought you meant to find the list of 3 element subsets of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, then when I saw your desired output, I thought you meant the 3 element multi-sets of {1, 2, 3, ..., 7} (thinking you had missed some), then finally realized that you wanted 3 positive integers that add up to 7.

Comment: Actually my code does not work, that's the thing.... what I can get though is the sum of subset. What I need is the subsets themselves. By subset i mean [(5,1,1), (4,2,1), (3,3,1), (3,2,2)]

Comment: I don't see the error right away, but I think you'll get "repetitions" like (4, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (1, 4, 2), (2, 4, 1), (2, 1, 4) if you proceed along these lines without some restriction where "the next number I add is smaller than the previous number added to the list"

Comment: @TravisJ there's no "error" per se. Exemple : for p(7,3) branching out to p(5,1), using the (n-1, k-1) side, you'll get a base case of k == 1. Then from this (5,1), I need to add up k-1 +1 at this subset resulting (5,1,1). My problem is managing the final list through recursion appending +1.